# Proper way to update a multiple rows using an angular service

Tags: angular

Trying to understand how this should work.  I am using a spring microservice setup and this angular service call updates a single record:

Angular service:

```
save(recordModel) {
    recordModel.lastUpdated = new Date();
    recordModel.whoUpdated = this.loginService.getUserId();
    this.dataService.httpPut(recordModel._links.self.href, recordModel).subscribe(resp => { },
      (resp) => {
      this.logger.error("Save Failed", resp);
      this.dialogError(resp);
    });
  }
```

I need the ability to update certain json attributes for all records in the DB:

```
updateAttributeIds(interfaceName: string) {
    this.logger.info("Updating Attribute Id's");
    let syncIssues = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.dataSource.length; i++) {
      if(this.dataSource[i].attributes.attributeId != this.dataSource[i].id) {
        syncIssues ++;
        if(this.dataSource[i].attributes.interfaceName === interfaceName) {
        this.dataSource[i].attributes.attributeId = this.dataSource[i].id;
          this.logger.info("Updating", this.dataSource[i].id);
          this.save(this.dataSource[i]);
        }
      }
    }
    this.logger.warn("Updating Attribute Id's", syncIssues);
  }
```

This seems to work, but this.save(this.dataSource[i]); doesn't wait for the promise and I'm trying to figure out it if needs to, before it tries to update the next record. It feels like on a large dataset, eventually I'd run out of resources - or threads?  Just unclear on what is really happening.

Thanks

Comment: Let's say each save takes 5ms to send and get a response (which is probably pretty good). If you wanted to update 1000 rows in sequence, sending another after the previous has responded, it would take 0.5s to send all the data. at 100,000 rows, it would take 8.333 minutes to complete.

Also, if you send 100 rows and the server was down for a moment or otherwise not responding, 
`this.dialogError(resp);` may show the user an error dialog 100 times unless you account for multiple calls.

Comment: You're also using an observable here, not a promise. Either way, they are both non-blocking by default, aka code continues to run without waiting for them to complete.

It might be a good experiment for you to stress test the system. Send a huge number of rows and see what happens.

Comment: Ok, def an issue with dialogError(resp), thanks for pointing that out.  So, non-blocking calls will continue to queue up and run and my http intercepter will show me that things are still processing which is what need to happen, but yes - I'm putting a larger data set together - it's that I'm currently on a smaller server right now.  THANK YOU